# Collapse animation after a for loop

Tags: javascript, velo

Good morning everybody!

I'm programming a part of my website, in it when the user clicks the button a loading animation starts to run, but it loads for a short period of time, the images appear after the animation has already collapsed, my code looks like this:

```
$w('#button8').onClick(() => calcular());
function calcular() {
   expand(`loadingAnimation`)
   query.find().then(res => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
         if (array[0]) {
            $w('#image1').src = item.images;
         }
         if (array[1]) {
            $w('#image2').src = item.images;
         }
         if (array[2]) {
            $w('#image3').src = item.imagens;
            collapse(`loadingAnimation`)
         }
  }
 }
}
```

How do I make the loading animation collapse after all the images have already loaded and make them all appear at the same time? Should I use While?

Comment: Animation is complicated in JavaScript because JS is single threaded. This means that while you are in a loop, the display will not be updated. You can use `setTimeout` and `setInterval` to run timed animation steps, or you can use CSS animations (if applicable). Beyond that, doing animation is easier if you use Web/Open GL

Comment: setTimeout must serve very well, thank you so much!